# Shared, one-side-mutable state in multithreaded plugin architecture

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, synchronization, c++14

I have an application with a very simple plugin system that builds around a core that takes care of the heavy lifting, but leaves any processing beyond the basics to the plugins. Now I'd like to make that system multi threaded, or at the very least allow individual plugins to run their own threads so that they can block individually without freezing the core.

Naturally, that means making the core thread safe, so that plugins can freely operate on thread safe member functions of said core. This is not that hard for many cases, but the problem comes in when the result of one of these member functions is a (const) reference to some inner environment maintained by the core. Plugins must not modify it, but the core running in another thread may update it at any point in time while the plugin is still holding on to the reference and possibly still mid-processing.

Now I could just expose a mutex in the core and have plugins lock it for as long as they need the data to remain unchanged, but since that mutex will have to block the core event processing, holding it for too long will cause all kinds of unpleasantries. I'd really like to avoid that.

Another solution might be having the function that *would* return a reference, return a copy instead, but the environment can grow pretty large with many containers that contain yet more things, and copying all that is expensive.

Apart from steering cleer of any direct sharing and instead talking over sockets or pipes, these seem to be my options, although I can not decide which one I'd choose.

Which would be my best bet? What options that I have not considered might help me here?

Comment: Could the internal component be a shared pointer and the function return a shared pointer?  If you can do that then you could code your core where if the reference count of the shared pointer is greater than 1 then you cannot modify it.

Comment: Copying seems the right way to go because it absolves you of a lot of shared access headaches but if the plugins need "real time" access to data (changes), this might not be ideal - you don't indicate what the nature of the plugins' memory access is that might help the decision.

Answer (score 0):

This question is quite opinion-based, but based on past experience, I would recommend using copy-on-write. You could do it at the top level, copying the entire object, or you could do it piece by piece, which might address the overhead of copying. For example:

```
struct BigData;
struct Shared
{
    std::shared_ptr<const BigData> a;
    std::shared_ptr<const BigData> b;
    std::shared_ptr<const BigData> c;
}
```

You would then only copy the parts you modify and send over a copy of `Shared` to the plugin. So if you change something in `a`, `b` and `c` would still point to the same object but `a` would point to a new `BigData` which was copied from the original and then modified.